# Join tables with values depending on column value

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

i have 1 long table and 1 short table:

the long table looks like this:

```
LongTable:

+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Kabelnummer  |     GL   |more data |even more |           
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1            |    850   |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 2            |    850   |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 3            |   1300   |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 4            |   1300   |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

and

```
ShortTable:

+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| data         |     GL   |more data |numericVal|           
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
|      x       |    850   |    x     | 0.2345   |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
|      x       |   1300   |    x     | 0.2849   |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I would like a query that copies the column "numericVal" into the table "LongTable" where GL.Longtable is the same as GL.shorttable:

```
LongTable:

+--------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Kabelnummer  |     GL   |more data |even more |numericVal|          
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1            |    850   |    x     |    x     | 0.2345   |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 2            |    850   |    x     |    x     | 0.2345   |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 3            |   1300   |    x     |    x     | 0.2849   |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 4            |   1300   |    x     |    x     | 0.2849   |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to join both tables with `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT L.*, s.numericVal 
  FROM LongTable l 
  JOIN sortTable s
    ON l.GL = s.GL
```

Comment: @Gutanoth add `INNER` before `JOIN`

Comment: Thanks it worked! My problem was that one of the tables had "GL" as MEMO filetype

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT lt.Kabelnummer, lt.GL, lt.X, lt.Y, st.numericVal
FROM LongTable lt
INNER JOIN ShortTable st ON lt.GL = st.GL
```

You use a `JOIN` to accomplish this.

You can read about joins here:

[Join Fundamentals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)